# Rのファイル出力： ベクトルと行列を1つの行に出力したい

Tags: r

Rのファイル出力に関してです．

次のようなベクトルと行列があったときに，

```
x <- c(1:3)
y <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
z <- matrix(1:15, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
```

このようなcsvを出力したいです．

```
1,1,4,7,1,4,7,10,13\n
2,2,5,8,2,5,8,11,14\n
3,3,6,9,3,6,9,12,15\n
```

変数で表すとこうなります．

```
x[1],y[1,],z[1,]
x[2],y[2,],z[2,]
x[3],y[3,],z[3,]
```

単に

```
write.table(y[1,],"test.csv", append = T,quote = F,sep=",",row.names = F,col.names = F)
```

というふうにやると

```
1\n
4\n
7\n
```

となってしまってダメでした．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こういう事でしょうか？

```
> cbind(as.matrix(x), y, z)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    4    7    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]    2    2    5    8    2    5    8   11   14
[3,]    3    3    6    9    3    6    9   12   15

> write.table(cbind(as.matrix(x), y, z), "test.csv",
              quote = F, sep=",", row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

> 行列にNAが含まれていて，NAの要素を詰めて出力する際にはどうしたら良いでしょうか

以下ではどうでしょうか。

```
apply(cbind(as.matrix(x), y, z), 1,
      function(r){
        write.table(t(r[!is.na(r)]), "test.csv",
                    append=T, quote = F, sep=",", row.names = F, col.names = F) })
```

※ `append=T` としていますので、複数回実行すると追記されていく事になります

Comment: ありがとうございます．できました．

追加で教えていただきたいのですが，

行列にNAが含まれていて，NAの要素を詰めて出力する際にはどうしたら良いでしょうか

Comment: @kamioka  書いてみました。試してみて下さい。